# use of io.Manager class in socket.io

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

**Socket.io** has provided docs about **io.Manager** class. It also tells about how to make a **manager** object. But it does not use this manager object anywhere in any example.

I want to ask whether this Manager class has any practical use or not. Since I am new to **Socket.io**, it would be helpful if someone tell the use of **manager** object with an example in layman way. If there is no direct use of manager object in making an application, then confirm it also.

Answer (score 0):

See these docs: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#manager

> The `Manager` manages the Engine.IO client instance, which is the low-level engine that establishes the connection to the server (by using transports like WebSocket or HTTP long-polling). The `Manager` handles the reconnection logic. A single `Manager` can be used by several Sockets.

> **Please note that, in most cases, you won't use the `Manager` directly but use the Socket instance instead.**